# RabbitListenerConfigureIntegrationTests Example

Tags: spring-amqp

I am looking for some integration test examples for RabbitListenerConfigurer and RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar and calling @rabbitListner annotation and test the message conversion and pass additional paramenters such as Channel and message properties etc.
Some thing like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RabbitListenerConfigureIntegrationTests {

    public final String sampleMessage="{\"ORCH_KEY\":{\"inputMap\":{},\"outputMap\":{\"activityId\":\"10001002\",\"activityStatus\":\"SUCCESS\"}}}";

    @Test
    public void testRabiitListenerConfigurer() throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                EnableRabbitConfigWithCustomConversion.class);
        RabbitListenerConfigurer registrar = ctx.getBean(RabbitListenerConfigurer.class);
        /* I want to get the Listener instance here */
        Message message = MessageBuilder.withBody(sampleMessage.getBytes())
                 .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                .setContentType("application/json")
                .build())
                 .build();
        /* call listener.onmessage(message) and that intern pass the call back to @rabbit listener and by that time MessageHandler which is registered should kick off and convert the message */
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableRabbit
    public static class EnableRabbitConfigWithCustomConversion implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
            registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());

        }

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory mockConnectionFactory() {
            return mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConnectionFactory(mockConnectionFactory());
            factory.setAutoStartup(false);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
            DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
            messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
            return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean 
        public  Listener messageListener1() {
            return new Listener();
        }

    }

public class Listener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "QUEUE")
    public void listen(ExchangeDTO dto, Channel chanel) {
        System.out.println("Result:" + dto.getClass() + ":" + dto.toString());
        /*ExchangeDTO dto = (ExchangeDTO)messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
        System.out.println("dto:"+dto);*/
    }
}
```

EDIT 2
I am not getting Exchange DTO populated with values. instead I get Null values 
Here is Log :
15:00:50.994 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=byte[93], headers={contentType=application/json, id=8bf86bf1-7e45-d136-9126-69959f92f100, timestamp=1552680050993}]]
Result:class com.dsicover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.ExchangeDTO:DTO [inputMap={}, outputMap={}]

```
public class ExchangeDTO implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private HashMap<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        private HashMap<String, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public HashMap<String, Object> getInputMap() {
            return inputMap;
        }

        public void setInputMap(HashMap<String, Object> inputMap) {
            this.inputMap = inputMap;
        }

        public HashMap<String, Object> getOutputMap() {
            return outputMap;
        }

        public void setOutputMap(HashMap<String, Object> outputMap) {
            this.outputMap = outputMap;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DTO [inputMap=" + this.inputMap + ", outputMap=" + this.outputMap + "]";
        }
}
```

Is there any thing i am missing in  Jackson2MessageConverter.

Answer (score 1):

- Give the @RabbitListener an `id`
- `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(id);`
- cast container to `AbstractMessageListenerContainer`
- `container.getMessageListener()`
- cast listener to `ChannelAwareMessageListener`
- call `onMessage()`.
- use a mock channel and verify expected call

**EDIT**

```
@Autowired
private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    AbstractMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            (AbstractMessageListenerContainer) this.registry.getListenerContainer("foo");
    ChannelAwareMessageListener listener =
            (ChannelAwareMessageListener) listenerContainer.getMessageListener();
    Channel channel = mock(Channel.class);
    listener.onMessage(new Message("foo".getBytes(),
            MessagePropertiesBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .setDeliveryTag(42L)
                .build()), channel);
    verify(channel).basicAck(42L, false);
}
```

**EDIT2**

Your json does not look like a DTO, it looks like a `Map<String, DTO>`.

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55188061Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55188061Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(id = "foo", queues = "foo")
    public void listen(Map<String, Foo> in, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(in);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private HashMap<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        private HashMap<String, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        public HashMap<String, Object> getInputMap() {
            return this.inputMap;
        }


        public void setInputMap(HashMap<String, Object> inputMap) {
            this.inputMap = inputMap;
        }


        public HashMap<String, Object> getOutputMap() {
            return this.outputMap;
        }


        public void setOutputMap(HashMap<String, Object> outputMap) {
            this.outputMap = outputMap;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [inputMap=" + this.inputMap + ", outputMap=" + this.outputMap + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So55188061ApplicationTests {

    public final String sampleMessage =
                "{\"ORCH_KEY\":{\"inputMap\":{},"
            + "\"outputMap\":{\"activityId\":\"10001002\",\"activityStatus\":\"SUCCESS\"}}}";

    @Autowired
    private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        AbstractMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (AbstractMessageListenerContainer) this.registry
                .getListenerContainer("foo");
        ChannelAwareMessageListener listener = (ChannelAwareMessageListener) listenerContainer.getMessageListener();
        Channel channel = mock(Channel.class);
        listener.onMessage(MessageBuilder.withBody(sampleMessage.getBytes())
                .andProperties(MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance()
                        .setContentType("application/json")
                        .setDeliveryTag(42L)
                        .build())
                .build(),
                channel);
        verify(channel).basicAck(42L, false);
    }

}
```

and

```
{ORCH_KEY=Foo [inputMap={}, outputMap={activityId=10001002, activityStatus=SUCCESS}]}
```

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thanks a a lot  Gary, But my Dto is empty do I need to add configure some property to my mapper. 
Log messages 
15:00:50.994 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=byte[93], headers={contentType=application/json, id=8bf86bf1-7e45-d136-9126-69959f92f100, timestamp=1552680050993}]]
Result:class com.dsicover.dftp.scrubber.subscriber.ExchangeDTO:DTO [inputMap={}, outputMap={}]

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question; delete these comments and comment that you have done so; also edit the question to show your current test case.

Comment: Your JSON is badly-formed - it looks like a `Map<String, DTO>`. I edited my answer with your test code and it works fine. Also, please learn to format code here; it must be indented by 4 bytes. Select the code and (Command-K on Mac).

Comment: I am sorry I am new here. I will format the code here after! and thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Can we also pass Header and message properties of the original message into Listener ?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't ask new questions in comments. `..., @Header("longHeaderName") long longHeader, @Headert("stringHeadertName") String StringHeader)`.

Comment: Sure Gary Thanks. I will write Test and validate in case I find some problem I will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your complex requirement to have everything on board, I don't see how we can make a deal with the `mock(ConnectionFactory.class)`. We would need to mock much more to have everything working.

Instead, I would suggest to take a look into the *real* integration test against existing RabbitMQ or at least embedded QPid.

In addition you may consider to use a `@RabbitListenerTest` to *spy* your `@RabbitListener` invocation without interfering your production code.

More info is in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#test-harness

Comment: You don't need to mock everything; just get a reference to the listener via the listener registrar.